# How to create list item that looks like its TextViews are bigger than it?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, background

I have a listview and need to create listitem that has labels (star and 15 min) that slightly stand out of list item- looks like they are bigger.

[image]

What kind of background must i make for listitem layout?

Comment: make a background that has a few pixels of transparency at the top.

Comment: yes, always use 9 patch, since the content can stretch the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a background that has a few pixels of transparency at the top with a 9patch image, no need for a XML shape (unless you are drawing the background there), just use a PNG file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

just create a custom listview Adapter for your listview

Comment: READ the question before posting answers.

Comment: in custom listview adapter ... row is we create by xml file. in xml  file use relativelayout .. in that just place this two labels at .. star label as  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" and android:id="@+id/starlabel" for star label ... next 15min label as android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/starlabel"  ... then problem solve

Comment: Some right margin too, but that was still not the question. He wanted to know how to create the background.

Comment: You need to be more specific when putting up your answers if you want people to upvote u :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Background Shape xml which is transparent about 8dp, then use that xml as your listview background